# UITableViewCell is getting allocated again and again while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

If a UITableViewCell has been allocated ,while scrolling, it should not be reallocated. It is however. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: You have to wrote some code for what are doing exactly so we can get idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the cell then code in cellForRowAtIndexPath some thing like that

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) 
    {
     CGRect CellFrame;

        CGRect nameLabelFrame; 

        CGRect countLabelFrame;

        CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);

        nameLabelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 270, 50);
        countLabelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 58, 270, 12);


        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UILabel *lblTemp;
        //UIImageView *imgTemp;

        lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameLabelFrame];
        lblTemp.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
        [lblTemp release];



        lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:countLabelFrame];
        lblTemp.tag = 3;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
        [lblTemp release];

}

//And outside of if condition access these labels by this

    //UIConstruction
        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

        UILabel *countLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
```

and use these labels or controls what you want outside this if condition

Comment: `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier` was deprecated in like 3.0, and height is now set with the delegate method. Also, instead of using tags, it'd be a lot better to subclass UITableViewCell and set the UILabels as properties of that class, specially since they can be resized when the cell is resized by overriding `setFrame:`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez By setting frame that does not mean, you are not going to use heightForRowAtIndexPath. this is for adjusting frame.also i am not giving exact solution.only an idea, no one going to write whole code.also there are another method for reusing the cell.so solution is reuse the cell.

Comment: @Ishu: I'm well aware it's just an idea, but imo you are not doing a good job presenting it. First of all, as I pointed out, you are using a long deprecated method, which might result in strange behavior and confuse the OP even more. Then you are adding random labels he might not need. When you make a UITableViewController from a template you get a perfectly good example of working reusable cells, why not go with that one? I think your answer could be greatly improved (starting by removing the deprecated method!).

Comment: Thanks Kingofbliss for your answer but I have already checked this way previously and its not working.